# PowerShell: Find unique values from multiple CSV files

Tags: powershell

let's say that I have several CSV files and I need to check a specific column and find values that exist in one file, but not in any of the others. I'm having a bit of trouble coming up with the best way to go about it as I wanted to use `Compare-Object` and possibly keep all columns and not just the one that contains the values I'm checking.

So I do indeed have several CSV files and they all have a `Service Code` column, and I'm trying to create a list for each `Service Code` that only appears in one file. So I would have "Service Codes only in CSV1", "Service Codes only in CSV2", etc.

Based on some testing and a [semi-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3897568/15243610), I've come up with a workable solution, but with all of the nesting and `For` loops, I'm wondering if there is a more elegant method out there.

Here's what I do have:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "C:\temp\ItemCompare" -Include "*.csv"
$HashList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]]]::New()
For ($i = 0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++){
    $TempHashSet = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]]::New([String[]](Import-Csv $files[$i])."Service Code")
    $HashList.Add($TempHashSet)
}

$FinalHashList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]]]::New()
For ($i = 0; $i -lt $HashList.Count; $i++){
    $UniqueHS = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]]::New($HashList[$i])
    For ($j = 0; $j -lt $HashList.Count; $j++){
        #Skip the check when the HashSet would be compared to itself
        If ($j -eq $i){Continue}
        $UniqueHS.ExceptWith($HashList[$j])
    }
    $FinalHashList.Add($UniqueHS)
}
```

It seems a bit messy to me using so many different .NET references, and I know I could make it cleaner with a tag to say `using namespace System.Collections.Generic`, but I'm wondering if there is a way to make it work using `Compare-Object` which was my first attempt, or even just a simpler/more efficient method to filter each file.

Comment: Which one of the CSVs you have is the "Reference CSV", or are you looking to compare all of them and find unique values ? Also, are you looking for efficiency or elegance, this is personal opinion but `hashshet` is a lot more elegant and efficient than `Compare-Object` (again, personal preference)

Comment: Can there be duplicates of service codes within a single file?

Comment: There most likely won't be duplicates within a single file, 99.9% of the time. @SantiagoSquarzon - I'm trying to compare each one to all others. So if I used `Compare-Object` it got pretty nested and probably doesn't qualify as elegant by any definition

Comment: I don't see you having `[System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase` on your `hashset`, is that something you should worry about ? (having too codes that might have the same value except for their difference in case sensitivity)

Comment: I could toss case logic in as a safety check, but everything should be converted to upper case in the source files so that isn't a big concern. The `HashSet` process isn't too bad and it rather quick, but now I'm starting to think I might to export the results including columns other than "Service Code" so before I converted everything to `HashTables` with `PSCustomObject`s as the keys, I thought I would check if there is a better approach entirely as I couldn't get `Compare-Object` to be happy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found an "elegant" solution based on `Group-Object`, using only a single pipeline:

```
# Import all CSV files. 
Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot\csv\*.csv -File -PipelineVariable file | Import-Csv | 

    # Add new column "FileName" to distinguish the files.
    Select-Object *, @{ label = 'FileName'; expression = { $file.Name } } |

    # Group by ServiceCode to get a list of files per distinct value. 
    Group-Object ServiceCode |

    # Filter by ServiceCode values that exist only in a single file.
    # Sort-Object -Unique takes care of possible duplicates within a single file.
    Where-Object { ( $_.Group.FileName | Sort-Object -Unique ).Count -eq 1 } |

    # Expand the groups so we get the original object structure back.
    ForEach-Object Group |

    # Format-Table requires sorting by FileName, for -GroupBy.
    Sort-Object FileName |

    # Finally pretty-print the result.
    Format-Table -Property ServiceCode, Foo -GroupBy FileName
```

### Test Input

**a.csv:**

```text
ServiceCode,Foo
1,fop
2,fip
3,fap
```

**b.csv:**

```text
ServiceCode,Foo
6,bar
6,baz
3,bam
2,bir
4,biz
```

**c.csv:**

```text
ServiceCode,Foo
2,bla
5,blu
1,bli
```

### Output

```text
   FileName: b.csv    

ServiceCode Foo       
----------- ---       
4           biz       
6           bar       
6           baz       

   FileName: c.csv    

ServiceCode Foo       
----------- ---       
5           blu
```

Looks correct to me. The values `1`, `2` and `3` are duplicated between multiple files, so they are excluded. `4`, `5` and `6` exist only in single files, while `6` is a duplicate value only within a single file.

### Understanding the code

Maybe it is easier to understand how this code works, by looking at the intermediate output of the pipeline produced by the `Group-Object` line:

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 1                         {@{ServiceCode=1; Foo=fop; FileName=a.csv}, @{ServiceCode=1; Foo=bli; FileName=c.csv}}
    3 2                         {@{ServiceCode=2; Foo=fip; FileName=a.csv}, @{ServiceCode=2; Foo=bir; FileName=b.csv}, @{ServiceCode=2; Foo=bla; FileName=c.csv}}
    2 3                         {@{ServiceCode=3; Foo=fap; FileName=a.csv}, @{ServiceCode=3; Foo=bam; FileName=b.csv}}
    1 4                         {@{ServiceCode=4; Foo=biz; FileName=b.csv}}
    1 5                         {@{ServiceCode=5; Foo=blu; FileName=c.csv}}
    2 6                         {@{ServiceCode=6; Foo=bar; FileName=b.csv}, @{ServiceCode=6; Foo=baz; FileName=b.csv}}
```

Here the `Name` contains the unique `ServiceCode` values, while `Group` "links" the data to the files.

From here it should already be clear how to find values that exist only in single files. If duplicate `ServiceCode` values within a single file wouldn't be allowed, we could even simplify the filter to `Where-Object Count -eq 1`. Since it was stated that dupes within single files may exist, we need the `Sort-Object -Unique` to count multiple equal file names within a group as only one.

Comment: `Group-Object` - I had originally thought about doing something similar to this when I came across `Compare-Object`. By the time I gave up last night to get `Compare` to work though, I went straight for a `hash set` and completely forgot about `Group-Object`! I'll give this a shot, but it looks promising and doesn't loop through all the files multiple times

Comment: @immobile2 This was an interesting exercise for me. I hope it works out for you.

Comment: Yeah this is perfect actually - plenty to expand on if needed, but a great approach. I usually don't even try to keep things in a single pipeline which probably explains why I've never even used `-PipelineVariable` before. Your explanation on the intermediary output is extremely helpful as well. `Group-Object` is definitely a bit underrated considering how powerful it can be

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but you obviously know what you're doing and I'm not sure how to move this to a chat. 1) I always seem to have trouble with `Add-Member` and whether I need to use `ForEach-Object{$_|Add-Member}` or I can just pipe directly into it. Why did you use `Select-Object` for a calculated property vs. `Add-Member`?

Comment: @immobile2 A big difference is that `Add-Member` modifies the object in-place, whereas `Select-Object` creates a copy before adding the member(s). In our case it propably wouldn't matter much, but in general I like to keep the original objects unmodified, which makes the program easier to reason about. So I rarely use `Add-Member` at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is not completely clear what you expect as an output.
If this is just the **ServiceCodes that intersect** then this is actually a duplicate with:

- [Comparing two arrays & get the values which are not common](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872835/1701026)
- [Union and Intersection in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609448/1701026)

But taking that you actually want the related object and files, you might use this approach:

```
$HashTable = @{}
ForEach ($File in Get-ChildItem .\*.csv) {
    ForEach ($Object in (Import-Csv $File)) {
        $HashTable[$Object.ServiceCode] = $Object |Select-Object *,
            @{ n='File'; e={ $File.Name } },
            @{ n='Count'; e={ $HashTable[$Object.ServiceCode].Count + 1 } }
    }
}
$HashTable.Values |Where-Object Count -eq 1
```

Comment: This looks nice and succinct and is propably faster than my long pipeline. The code currently does not output a ServiceCode value when it is duplicated only in a single file. This could be solved by storing the file names in a `HashSet` instead of incrementing a counter. Then use `HashSet.Count` in the `Where-Object` condition.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find those related questions when I was looking for a method to the madness, but I do think my exercise is essentially a duplicate of those since what I want as output wasn't even fully clear to me when I started the project. At first I just wanted the list of intersecting values (or those that don't intersect I suppose), but realized that returning the full objects and finishing by writing them to a file would be more helpful than just the values. Thanks for linking those related answers which are superb and for tackling my question!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this fun exercise, I'm using a similar approach as yours with the [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0) but adding `[System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase` to leverage the [`.Contains(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-hashset-1-contains(-0)) method:

```sh
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

# Generate Random CSVs:
$charset = 'abABcdCD0123xXyYzZ'
$ran = [random]::new()
$csvs = @{}
foreach($i in 1..50) # Create 50 CSVs for testing
{
    $csvs["csv$i"] = foreach($z in 1..50) # With 50 Rows
    {
        $index = (0..2).ForEach({ $ran.Next($charset.Length) })
        
        [pscustomobject]@{
            ServiceCode = [string]::new($charset[$index])
            Data = $ran.Next()
        }
    }
}

# Get Unique 'ServiceCode' per CSV:
$result = @{}
foreach($key in $csvs.Keys)
{
    # Get all unique `ServiceCode` from the other CSVs
    $tempHash = [HashSet[string]]::new(
        [string[]]($csvs[$csvs.Keys -ne $key].ServiceCode),
        [System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase
    )
    # Filter the unique `ServiceCode`
    $result[$key] = foreach($line in $csvs[$key])
    {
        if(-not $tempHash.Contains($line.ServiceCode))
        {
            $line
        }
    }
}

# Test if the code worked,
# If something is returned from here means it didn't work
foreach($key in $result.Keys)
{
    $tmp = $result[$result.Keys -ne $key].ServiceCode
    foreach($val in $result[$key])
    {
        if($val.ServiceCode -in $tmp)
        {
            $val
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @immobile2 omg you're right, not sure why `$result = @{}` is not here. I might have missed it when copy-pasting... I have updated. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get unique items as follow

```
# Get all items of CSVs in a single variable with adding the file name at the last column
$CSVs = Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\ItemCompare\*.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $CSV = Import-CSV -Path $_.FullName
    $FileName = $_.Name
    $CSV | Select-Object *,@{N='Filename';E={$FileName}}
}
Foreach($line in $CSVs){
$ServiceCode = $line.ServiceCode
$file = $line.Filename
if (!($CSVs | where {$_.ServiceCode -eq $ServiceCode -and $_.filename -ne $file})){
$line
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This approach definitely works, but it seems to be quite a bit slower than what I was clocking with `Compare-Object`, `Group-Object`, or using a ton of hash tables and hash sets. Which makes sense because I was leaning toward a dictionary/hash table of some sort for the speed of lookups and compares, with the number of files that I have in the folder the `Where-Object` filtering here seems to bring things to a near standstill